# Android Tabhost Problem - .setIndicator

Tags: android, android-widget, tabwidget, android-tabhost

First let me clarify that i have already referred the SO question related to "Android - TAbhost".

I have done googling about "Android Tabhost" but failed to find the solution.

My problem is:

If are having <3 tabs then it is fine. 
but
Supporse if we are having 4 tabs with indicator title as TabHost1, TabHost2, TabHost3, TabHost4). But this title in Tab does not get fitted with tab. so **is there any way to fit the Title Text (i.e. indicator) inside the tab ??**

Comment: That's a good question. I would have said use the weight but actually, you don't have access to it...

Comment: i think he refers to `layout_weight` (i'm guessing)

Comment: That's right but as i said, it can't work for this. I've looked for it and couldn't access this property for the tab.

Comment: @Sephy my problem is that 4 tabs are shown ...but inner text are displyed in marquee effect

Comment: yeah I know, I have the same issue, that's why I marked your question as favorite

Comment: @Sephy glad to know....hope we together find out the solution

Comment: However, what would you like to have? because the purpose of this is I suppose to be able to have all tabs on the screen at the same time no? but then how would you like your tabs?

Comment: Ok, I think I have isolated the source of the issue, look at my answer because it won't fit in comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought the source of our issue was somewhere in the framework's code. And sure enough, I found some clues :

First, if you look inside the [`TabWidget` code](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=fr#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/TabWidget.java&q=class:translateanimation&d=3&l=89), you will see that the label you set in `setIndicator` is passed to an inner class called `LabelIndicatorStrategy` which will take care of inflating the view associated to the top part of the tab. This inflation is done using an xml file [tab_indicator.xml](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch/p?hl=fr#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/layout/tab_indicator.xml&q=tab_indicator&exact_package=git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc). This layout is based on a `RelativeLayout` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. And if you look at the properties of the textview, you will see that it refers to a style in android [styles.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml#l517). And here finally, you realize that we have THAT :

```
<item name="ellipsize">marquee</item>
<item name="singleLine">true</item>
```

So, now, 2 options :
First, override the style by creating your own style, which in my opinion would be the really painless way and then change these properties to something that suits you better. Though the result might not be very nice. this will require some testing.
Or, put on your gloves and copy the code from the TabWidget class, because another issue here is that the inner class I mentionned is... PRIVATE so, no inheritance possible if I'm not mistaken... SO I think, much much more pain than the styles.xml's way.
Hope this will inspire you, keep me posted of what you get please. I'm still interested.

Comment: gr8 answer...let me try and sure reply you about whatever happens

Answer (score 1):

i have solved the above issue by decreasing the size of Font, check the below code of **`Style.xml`**:

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/LightTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LightTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">12px</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#1E90FF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You can also try to move the characters together by using the android:textScaleX tag.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean i didnt get what you are talking about? so pls can you ellaborate your comment with more specific detail

Comment: Mayani: Yes sorry if it was confusing. I meant that you can also kind of "compress" the text in the tab by using textScaleX which will result in a more "compact" text. That way you can sometimes use the same text size for every TabIndicator text even tho one text might be longer and wouldn't fit. I guess to see what I mean you gotta try it.

Comment: @Octavian Damiean oh my god, this is the simple way instead of doing the style modification, thanx for letting me know, really a simple step